# Error de token pero ¿dónde está?

Tags: bash

Necesito su ayuda en mi código bash, revisé el código unas 10 veces, un buen momento y esto es perfecto, lo proporcioné en kali linux y termux (android) pero da un error cuando se ejecuta el código, solo en el línea del elif ..

El error que da es: error de sintaxis cerca del token inesperado 'elif' (verifique los elifs y no encontró ningún error en ellos)

El código es eso y quería subirlo a Github pero debido a ese problema no puedo ... Tu ayuda sería un gran favor ^^

```
    read vw

if [ $vw = 1 ]
then
        sleep 1.3
        https://github.com/Tuhinshubhra/RED_HAWK
        bash tools.sh

elif [ $vw = 2 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/VWolf13/fakeroot
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 3 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/thehackingsage/hacktronian
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 4 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/the-robot/sqliv
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 5 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/llaera/slowloris.pl
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 6 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/thelinuxchoice/userrecon
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 7 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/sabri-zaki/EasY_HaCk
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 8 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/Gameye98/Lazymux
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 9 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/maldevel/IPGeoLocation
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 10 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/m4ll0k/Infoga
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 11 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/VWolf13/lang-esp
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 12 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/sundowndev/PhoneInfoga
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

elif [ $vw = 13 ]
then
        sleep 0.5
        git clone https://github.com/llaera/slowloris.pl
        bash tools.sh
        sleep 1.3

else
        sleep 0.5
        echo "El número introducido no coincide con ninguno existente, intentalo nuevamente"
        bash tools.sh
        fi
fi
```

Thanks for reading, if you find the solution, he says, there is no way I can find it...

Comment: hay muchos `elif` aquí. Indica qué comando ejecutas exactamente cuando te da error. También es bueno pegar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net para que te corrija los errores más comunes

Comment: Muchas gracias por esa recomendación, lo tomare mucho en cuenta ^^

Answer (score 3):

Si le das una ojeada rápida a tu código, el error se puede ver fácilmente en la penúltima sentencia `fi`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tiene sentido ese `fi` ahí.

Por otra parte; la pagina que @fedorqui te recomendó ([shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)) te indica todas las anomalías de tu script, incluyendo la de tu pregunta inicial.